# how can i apply multiple color for single bar in bar chart using AchartEngine in Android?

Tags: android, achartengine

[image]
 I want to make my bar chart as per image but i don't know how can change bar color after some point of y axis also i want to draw a line (Red-line in image) at specific point of y axis as in image.Please help me how can i do it?My code for chart view is

```
private void ChartView() {

            String[] titles = new String[] { " " };

        //  int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE };
            multiRenderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
            multiRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);

            multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
            multiRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DCDCDC"));
            setChartSettings(multiRenderer, "Calorie-Consume-Chart", chatX_lable,chatY_lable, -4,
                    6, 0, 240, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
            multiRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(0).setDisplayChartValues(true);
            //multiRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(1).setDisplayChartValues(true);

            multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
            multiRenderer.setYLabels(10);
            multiRenderer.clearXTextLabels();
            multiRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
            multiRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
            multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
            // renderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
            multiRenderer.setZoomRate(1.1f);
            multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.7);
            multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
            multiRenderer.


            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.weightlinl);
            layout.removeAllViews();
            if (mChartView == null) {
                mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this,
                        buildBarDataset(titles, weekly_data_int)/* dataset */,
                        multiRenderer,org.achartengine.chart.BarChart.Type.DEFAULT);
                layout.addView(mChartView);
            } else {
                // mChartView.repaint();

                mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this,
                        buildBarDataset(titles, weekly_data_int), multiRenderer,
                        org.achartengine.chart.BarChart.Type.DEFAULT);
                mChartView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                layout.addView(mChartView);

                // mChartView.repaint();
            }
            mChartView.invalidate();
        }

        protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer,
                String title, String xTitle, String yTitle, double xMin,
                double xMax, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor,
                int labelsColor) {
            renderer.setChartTitle(title);
            renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
            renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);
            renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);
            renderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);
            renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
            renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);
            renderer.setInitialRange(range);
            renderer.clearXTextLabels();
            renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);

            renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);
        }

        protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors) {
            XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
            renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(12);
            renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(16);
            renderer.setLabelsTextSize(12);
            renderer.setLegendTextSize(12);
            int length = colors.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
                r.setColor(colors[i]);
                renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
            }
            return renderer;
        }

        protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(String[] titles, int j) {
            XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
            int length = titles.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(titles[i]);
                series.add(j);

                dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
            }
            return dataset;
        }
![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKyjg.png
```

Comment: if you want to show bar charts without any jars, you can try [this example](https://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/bar-chart-in-android-with-out-any-built-in-jars/). if you can get your requirement if you change the listview row item according to your needs

Comment: @Ramkiran i want to draw bar as per image means after 1500 value i want to change the color of the same bar

Comment: @Raj -- Did you get the complete answer for above one. if yes please share me.

Comment: @Siri if u want to perform same function i recommend you to use MPAndroidChart.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following hacks might work for you:

- For your first requirement, try to use the stacked bar chart. It may be a bit tricky to manage but it should work
- For drawing a straight line, I am not sure if the AchartEngine library provides any such method. Either you can use a line chart to draw a straight line or you can make changes in the library to add the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This might will solve your problem:

renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(0).setGradientEnabled(true);

renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(0).setGradientStart(0,
                Color.rgb(025, 117, 025));

renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(0).setGradientStop(yMaxVal/2,
                Color.rgb(94, 158, 94));

use setGradientStart and stop to define color after some point in your bar.